# Как называется боль в мышцах после тренировки?

Tags: одним-словом

Известно, что после тренировки, особенно после длительной паузы, мышцы несколько дней болят. Как называется это явление?

> Ребята, я с вами не выйду гулять. У меня ??? после тренировки.

Comment: Так и скажите: боль в мышцах. Все поймут.

Comment: Я бы сказала "ноги болят" или "руки болят" (ну или подставьте нужное вплоть до "все болит"). Как вриант — "ноги отваливаются" (или руки)

Comment: @ddbug если уж без отдельного слова, то я б сказал "мышцы ноют".

Comment: Растяжение мышц.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Я не знаю, насколько это слово корректно с научной, медицинской точки зрения, но в разговорной речи очень часто используется слово [`крепатура`](http://sportwiki.to/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) - так  называют любые болезненные ощущения после большой физической нагрузки.

Comment: Про разговорную речь - очень оптимистичное преувеличение. Думаю, что примерно 49 из 50 человек этого слова никогда не слышали и не поймут.

Comment: @Abakan разговорный - не значит общеупотребимый - это значит что те, кто ходят в качалки - это слово употребляют.

Comment: Я ходил в разные года в разных городах и только сегодня узнал о существовании такого слова.

Comment: @Abakan: I learned this word when I was doing fencing as a kid (late 80's and early 90's). Turned out my father (who was an athlete in late 50's) was also using it even back then.

Comment: @Quassnoi so you dad was from more or less professional sportsmen circles. I am pretty sure professional sport and medic circles do use professional Latin terms. But out of those circles I think the word has very little exposure.

Comment: @Arioch: if by "professional" you mean "competitive", then yes, he was (there was hardly any professional sport in the USSR back then, meaning the athletes did not make their living out of their performance).

Comment: друзья, давайте я заменю "разговорный" на "в обиходе" - и дело с концом!

Comment: @shabunc too late, you already have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Миалгия — мышечная боль, возникающая после нагрузок или без видимой причины.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, миалгия - это не про боль, возникающую после упражнений.

Comment: @shabunc, с мед. т. зр. миалгия - это симптом, является синонимом мышечной боли. Этиология миалгии может быть разной, в т.ч. может включать боль во время и после физических нагрузок, которые классифицируются на острую мышечную болезненность (аcute muscle soreness) и крепатуру, или синдром отсроченной мышечной боли (delayed onset muscle soreness). Миалгия - это общий медицинский термин, описывающий любую боль в мышцах как признак любого связанного заболевания (которые могут касаться физ. нагрузок или нет).

Comment: **в том числе может** включать, но тогда с тем же успехом можно сказать, что и "боль в мышцах"  это ответ - потому что боль в мышцах в том числе включает и боль во время и после физических нагрузок. При том я оставляю за скобками тот факт, что такой ответ в принципе уже был дан.

Answer (score 1):

> Ребята, я с вами не выйду гулять. У меня миалгия после тренировки.

Так называют это явление врачи.

Comment: 21 век, русские люди узнают новые слова русского языка на сайте для иностранцев :-D

Comment: @Arioch Это не сайт для иностранцев

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan именно что для иностранцев. Для носителей есть https://rus.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю как это называется по научному, но я привык называть это крепатурой)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Please do not repost existing answers. If you like an answer, please upvote it when you have enough reputation to do that. Thank you!